# How to import data into Excel from MS Access?

Tags: excel, database, import, onedrive-for-business, microsoft-access

If I put an MS Access database on Sharepoint or One Drive, how can I import/link the database table into Excel? My Excel will also eventually be on Sharepoint.

Current as a PoC, I put the database on my company One Drive, does it work the same as on Sharepoint?

I am also open to new database solution (instead of MS Access) that works well with Sharepoint today in 2018, Office365 subscription. Thanks!

Comment: Is your question about how to get Access data in to Excel?  Or is your question about how the Access database (or Excel?) will behave if it is saved in Sharepoint?

Comment: The database is MS Access which I want to put on Sharepoint. I wish to know how to import data from the database into Excel.

Comment: So you are asking how to import an Access DB into SP so you can export into Excel? What not just export the DB to Excel directly through the Access application?

Comment: @ChrisFells I don't want to import Access DB into SP. I want to put the .accdb file on Sharepoint, then in Excel, import from the .accdb file. .accdb file needs to be on sharepoint so everyone can update the database.

Comment: In that case the question may get flag for being off-topic. It appears its a generic question regarding excel.

Comment: @JamesRandal what is the solution now for hosting a database on Sharepoint? Maybe that's a better question?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So there are a couple of solutions depending on whether you have SP Enterprise or not.

Enterprise: Use OneDrive for Business (Really nothing more than a SP Library, but hey... it's branded) just like you would for regular OneDrive.

Enterprise/Non-Enterprise: Load the file to a document library. Make sure you have permissions enabled on the file for everyone who needs to access it. Then point to it just like you would otherwise.

There are specific web parts for both access and excel. I would recommend building a sandbox and making sure the connections work from your SP environment to both before putting this on a production environment.

And honestly, in using the Access webpart, you can allow people to edit directly without even needing to interface Excel so long as you have the webpart and forms setup correctly.

Comment: Seems there is no Access in the latest Sharepoint, is Access web discontinued?

Comment: Apparently in "Modern" Office suites (365 ProPlus, E3, and E5 and 2019 On Prem) Access is either PC only or completely non-existent (All the other versions not listed.) So while Access is not "dead" it would seem to be better to use something else, like Excel, which does have a web part tie-in instead. My apologies for not realizing, we are still on 2013 On Prem where I work and use SP, which DOES have an Access web part. Considering the functionality of SP with its lists (which are nothing but tables), it might be better to rebuild using SP lists and transferring the data.